# PayPal Advanced EmbeddedForm

Tags: paypal

Following the instructions in their documentation, I've successfully implemented a PayPal Advanced solution within an iFrame.  The process works fine using a credit card.  However, there are also two buttons that show up in the form for "Checkout with PayPal" and "Checkout with BillMeLater..."

When the user clicks either of these buttons, the window breaks out of the iframe and the session has expired.

Can this top of the form be hidden, or at the very least, be made to open within the iframe and keep the session, as it should?

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which layout option are you using?  A, B, or C?  It sounds like maybe you have a conflict there..??

[Chapter 3 of the PayFlow documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) covers this in depth.

Comment: Layout C.    I've been over Chapter 3 numerous times, and it tells me how to change colors, return pages, etc.  However, in the "Pay with PayPal" frame, the buttons still open in a new window (breaking out of the iframe), and show a session timeout error.

Comment: Might be something you need to post to www.paypal.com/mts

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I actually sent a support request to PayPal and didn't get a response.  I'll keep plugging away and see if I can come up with an answer.

Comment: You sent it through MTS?  I've been getting pretty quick responses from them lately.

Comment: When I submit through MTS, I get an email saying I submitted, and it tells me to "Click the link below" to review the status of the question.  But, there is no link below.   And, I never hear back from anyone.

Comment: Yea.. I'm stupid.  Kind of.  The MODE attribute was still set to Test in the last call.  Their PayFlow testing system is kind of pieced together it seems.  Hopefully, they'll get that cleaned up soon. Thanks for your time Andrew.